# How to search a field in array using elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using the index array field json as,

```
"productdetailsarray":
{
"properties":{
"producttone" : { "type" : "integer", "store" : "yes", "precision_step" : "8" },
"productsaleid" : { "type" : "integer", "store" : "yes", "precision_step" : "8" },
"productcoverage" : { "type" : "integer", "store" : "yes", "precision_step" : "8" },
"productdataid" : { "type" : "integer", "store" : "yes", "precision_step" : "8" },
"productid" : { "type" : "integer", "store" : "yes", "precision_step" : "8" }}
}
```

How to search the data inside the array?

Comment: which specific data you wanna search?

Comment: I need to search all the data inside productdetailsarray which sent as integer parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple parse the JSon using a library like GSon:

```
MyClassToModelTheData data = new Gson().fromJson(theJsonString, MyClassToModelTheData.class);
```

Once in object-form, you can use any of the standard Java constructs to search the data.

If you use Maven, you can use the following to import GSon:

```
<!-- For parsing JSon -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick update Jaco Van Niekerk. How can I pass the input string (search string) for search

Comment: I am using Java for searching.

Comment: Each of the fields (properties, producttone, etc.) are lists.  So I assume, simply searching with list.contains(search-string) should do the trick.